# In OpenRasta, how should you handle codec errors or exceptions?

Tags: openrasta

My scenario is this:

1. A client application executes a HTTP POST against an endpoint exposed by OpenRasta.
2. The body of the request contains an error that causes a problem in the codec - which is a custom implementation of `OpenRasta.Codecs.IMediaTypeReader`. This converts a JSON payload to the POCO expected by the handler.
3. The codec throws an exception that describes the error in a useful way. For example: `Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: After parsing a value an unexpected character was encountered: ". Line 4, position 5.`
4. The client application receives a HTTP 405 - MethodNotAllowed. The client doesn't see any of the exception details.

If the codec is modified to catch a `JsonReaderException` and return `Missing.Value`, similar to the [Implementing a codec](https://github.com/openrasta/openrasta/wiki/Implementing-a-Codec) wiki, then the client receives a HTTP 500 - Internal Server Error. The body of the response also describes the following exception:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: The operation is not ready for invocation.
   at OpenRasta.OperationModel.MethodBased.MethodBasedOperation.Invoke()
   at OpenRasta.OperationModel.Interceptors.OperationWithInterceptors.<Invoke>b__0()
   at OpenRasta.OperationModel.Interceptors.OperationWithInterceptors.Invoke()
   at OpenRasta.OperationModel.OperationExecutor.Execute(IEnumerable`1 operations)
   at OpenRasta.Pipeline.Contributors.OperationInvokerContributor.ExecuteOperations(ICommunicationContext context)
   at OpenRasta.Pipeline.PipelineRunner.ExecuteContributor(ICommunicationContext context, ContributorCall call)
```

How should I modify my application so that:

- The client receives a HTTP 400 Bad Request.
- The client receives a string containing the details of the exception encountered in the codec.

Comment: Found this related thread on Google Groups: http://groups.google.com/group/openrasta/browse_thread/thread/5deb77ebdc78d79f

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having found [this](http://groups.google.com/group/openrasta/browse_thread/thread/5deb77ebdc78d79f) thread on Google Groups which contains all the answers, my current implementation looks something like this.

Within my implementation of `IConfigurationSource`:

```
using (OpenRastaConfiguration.Manual)
{
    ResourceSpace.Uses.PipelineContributor<ErrorCheckingContributor>(); 

    // Other configuration here
}
```

Then `ErrorCheckingContributor` looks something like this:

```
public class ErrorCheckingContributor : IPipelineContributor
{
    public void Initialize(IPipeline pipelineRunner)
    {
        pipelineRunner
            .Notify(CheckRequestDecoding)
            .After<KnownStages.IOperationResultInvocation>()
            .And.Before<KnownStages.ICodecResponseSelection>(); 
    }

    private static PipelineContinuation CheckRequestDecoding(ICommunicationContext context)
    {
        if (context.ServerErrors.Count == 0)
        {
            return PipelineContinuation.Continue;
        }

        var first = context.ServerErrors[0];
        if (first.Exception is Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException)
        {
            context.Response.Entity.ContentType = MediaType.TextPlain;
            context.Response.Entity.ContentLength = first.Exception.Message.Length;
            using (var sw = new StreamWriter(context.Response.Entity.Stream))
            {
                sw.Write(first.Exception.Message);
            }
        }

        return PipelineContinuation.Continue;
    } 
}
```

There's some things to be aware of with the above:

- If a handler were to throw a `JsonReaderException`, it would also be processed here.
- It doesn't check what media types the client accepts. This is different from exceptions thrown by Handlers that do go through codec selection.
- Tried setting `context.OperationResult` to `context.ServerErrors` - but it doesn't go through the codec.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a minor variation of the answer above - this time with codec selection based on the operation result data.

Within `IConfigurationSource`:

```
using (OpenRastaConfiguration.Manual)
{
    ResourceSpace.Uses.PipelineContributor<ErrorCheckingContributor>(); 

    ResourceSpace.Has.ResourcesOfType<ApplicationError>()
                 .WithoutUri
                 .TranscodedBy<ApplicationErrorCodec>();

                 // Or use a generic JSON serializer like this:
                 // .AsJsonDataContract();

    // Other configuration here
}
```

Now `ErrorCheckingContributor` looks like this:

```
public class ErrorCheckingContributor : IPipelineContributor
{
  public void Initialize(IPipeline pipelineRunner)
  {
    pipelineRunner
        .Notify(CheckRequestDecoding)
        .After<KnownStages.IOperationResultInvocation>()
        .And.Before<KnownStages.ICodecResponseSelection>();
  }

  private static PipelineContinuation CheckRequestDecoding(ICommunicationContext context)
  {
    if (context.ServerErrors.Count == 0)
    {
      return PipelineContinuation.Continue;
    }

    Error err = context.ServerErrors[0];

    // Get a suitable message (err.Message contains stack traces, so try to avoid that)
    string msg = err.Title;
    if (msg == null && err.Exception != null)
      msg = err.Exception.Message;
    if (msg == null)
      msg = err.Message;

    // Create instance of an error information resource which is specific for the application
    // - This one is rather simple and only contains a copy of the message
    ApplicationError error = new ApplicationError(msg);

    // Set operation result to be "400 Bad Request" and remove errors
    context.OperationResult = new OperationResult.BadRequest { ResponseResource = error };
    context.ServerErrors.Clear();

    // Render immediately without starting any handlers
    return PipelineContinuation.RenderNow;
  }
}
```

The class `ApplicationError` is:

```
public class ApplicationError
{
  public string Message { get; set; }

  public ApplicationError(string message)
  {
    Message = message;
  }
}
```

At last we need a codec `ApplicationErrorCodec` for `ApplicationError`. This is not different from any other IMediaTypeWriter codec but depends a lot on your expected response media type. See https://github.com/openrasta/openrasta/wiki/Implementing-a-Codec for one example.